# Select top distinct products based on a distinct column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to write a sql server 2008 query that selects the top distinct products by a brandId ordered by the latest date published as in the following table:

```
dbo.Products
ProductId, BrandId, PublishedOn
```

Table contents:

```
1, 1, 2011-01-01
2, 2, 2011-01-01
3, 3, 2011-01-01
4, 1, 2011-01-09
5, 1, 2011-01-10
6, 2, 2011-01-10
```

The output i'm after is:

```
6, 2, 2011-01-10
5, 1, 2011-01-10
3, 3, 2011-01-01
```

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Apologies if the title is incorrect but i didnt quite know how to phrase this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want the latest row for each `BrandId` as ordered by `PublishedOn`?

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BrandId 
                                       ORDER BY PublishedOn DESC) AS RN
         FROM   dbo.Products)
SELECT ProductId,
       BrandId,
       PublishedOn
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. I dont suppose you could enlighten me about the starting semicolon per chance?

Comment: @SF - This is just to pre-empt the error you would get if you pasted it into a block of existing code that you don't terminate with semi colons. It is mandatory that the previous statement needs to be terminated with a semi colon.